# How to install new version of Wireshark on Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, qt

At my wits end. How do I force Xenial to upgrade or install Wireshark 2.3 since it's only got 2.2 in the repo?

I'm trying to use tshark --extract-objects command line function, which is available on tshark 2.3, to script a pcap file analysis.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and can't figure out for the life of me how to force the updated package.

lsb_relase -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

uname -a

```
Linux j-VirtualBox 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Xenial is using the 2.2, as show here, [Xenial Wireshark](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/net/wireshark)

I tried installing 2.3 from source and ran into dependency hell, then gave Wireshark 2.4 from source a shot. The first run errored out because it couldn't find QT. I followed the directions here [QT Install](https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu) but after installing QT and retrying wireshark, that ended with the following error-

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qmetatype.h:169:79: error: ‘qt_metatype_id’ is not a member of ‘QMetaTypeId<QToolBar*>’
     static inline int qt_metatype_id() { return QMetaTypeId<T>::qt_metatype_id(); }
                                                                               ^
main_window.cpp:221:13: warning: ‘void mainwindow_add_toolbar(const iface_toolbar*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void mainwindow_add_toolbar(const iface_toolbar *toolbar_entry)
             ^
main_window.cpp:229:13: warning: ‘void mainwindow_remove_toolbar(const gchar*)’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void mainwindow_remove_toolbar(const gchar *menu_title)
             ^
Makefile:1910: recipe for target 'main_window.o' failed
make[2]: *** [main_window.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/johnny/Desktop/scanner/malware/wireshark-2.4.1/ui/qt'
Makefile:3401: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/johnny/Desktop/scanner/malware/wireshark-2.4.1'
Makefile:1745: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: When I installed Avidemux, I needed to install Qt files. I installed these: `qttools5-dev-tools  qt4-qmake libqt4-dev`. You should try install them and check.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found this after figuring out how to ask the right question. Walk through on how to set up stable/testing/unstable together. [Running debian stable/testing](https://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing)